# Поиск тoвара по ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, поиск, search

У меня есть модели: категория, товар и описание товара.
Т.к. товаров слишком много и найти нужный товар, чтобы добавить описание, просто невозможно, нужно решить эту проблему:

1 вариант - поиск товара зная его ForeignKey.

2 вариант - сначала выбор категории товара, а потом товар.

Comment: Так в чем вопрос?

Comment: Нашел "django-autocomplete-light ", пробую его... Есть еще варианты поиска по ForeignKey ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для поиска в админке в админ-классе нужно прописать:

`search_fields = ('pk',)`

В этом случае будет реализован поиск по id. Через запятую можно добавить еще полей, по которым будет реализован поиск

Comment: Это вроде поиск по объектам, а мне нужен поиск при добавлении объекта, поиск по ForeignKey

Comment: тогда в класс добавьте строку 
`raw_id_fields = ("pk",)`

Answer (score 0):

Поиск товара по id:

`good = Good.objects.get(pk=good_id)`

Поиск товара из конкретной категории по id товара и id категории:

`good = Good.objects.get(pk=good_id, cat__id=cat_id)`

Comment: Это работает в админке джанго?

Comment: А разве было сказано, что надо искать в админке?

Comment: Забыл указать это. Про фильтрацию то знаю, а как в админке ..